# Rails elasticsearch - named scope search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm just moving over from the Tire gem to the official elasticsearch [Ruby wrapper](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby) and am working on implementing better search functionality.

I have a model `InventoryItem` and a model `Store`. `Store` has_many `:inventory_items`. I have a model scope on Store called `local`

```
scope :local, lambda{|user| near([user.latitude, user.longitude], user.distance_preference, :order => :distance)}
```

I want the search to only return results from this scope so I tried: `InventoryItem.local(user).search....` but it searches the entire index, not the scope. After doing some research, it looks like filter's are a good way to achieve this, but I'm unsure how to implement. I'm open to other ways of achieving this as well. My ultimate goal is be able to search a subset of the `InventoryItem` model based on store location.

Answer (score 8):

Another thing you can do is to send the list of valid ids right to elastic, so it will filter records out by itself and then perform a search on ones that left. We were not doing tests whether it is faster yet, but I think it should, because elastic is a search engine after all.

I'll try to compose an example using you classes + variables and our experience with that:

```
def search
  # retrieve ids you want to perform search within
  @store_ids = Store.local(current_user).select(:id).pluck(:id)
  # you could also check whether there are any ids available
  # if there is none - no need to request elastic to search
  @response = InventoryItem.search_by_store_ids('whatever', @store_ids)
end
```

And a model:

```
class InventoryItem
  # ...

  # search elastic only for passed store ids
  def self.search_by_store_ids(query, store_ids, options = {})       
    # use method below
    # also you can use it separately when you don't need any id filtering
    self.search_all(query, options.deep_merge({
      query: {
        filtered: {
          filter: {
            terms: {
              store_id: store_ids
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }))
  end

  # search elastic for all inventory items
  def self.search_all(query, options = {})
    self.__elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          filtered: {
            query: {
              # use your fields you want to search, our's was 'text'
              match: { text: query },
            },
            filter: {},
            strategy: 'leap_frog_filter_first' # do the filter first
          }
        }
      }.deep_merge(options)
      # merge options from self.search_by_store_ids if calling from there
      # so the ids filter will be applied
    )
  end
  # ...
end
```

That way you also have to index `store_id`.

You can read more about filters [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html).

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I agree it it could be faster. I'll award bounty - thank you for the detailed answer. I'll test this and provide feedback when I have a chance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer provided me a nice template and I was finally able to build a search that filters using a set of ids (I couldn't find the proper way to do that on Rails and was getting parse errors all the time).

Comment: This was great! I've been searching for a way to combine scopes with elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

**I'll leave this answer without accepting until the bounty is over - feel free to add an answer if you think you've found a better solution that one below.**

The answer to this ended up being fairly simple after some digging.

Using the named scope:

```
scope :for_stores, lambda{ |stores| where(store_id: stores.map(&:id)) }
```

My controller method:

```
def search
  @stores = Store.local(current_user) # get local stores
  response = InventoryItem.search 'whatever' # execute the search
  @inventory_items = response.records.for_stores(@stores) # call records
end
```

On elasticsearch responses, you can either call `records` or `results`. Calling just `results` will simply yield the results from the index that you can display etc. Calling `records` actually pulls the AR records which allows you to chain methods like I did above. Cool! More info in the [docs](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) obviously.