# Rails and Elasticsearch - Filters, weights, and statistics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, mongoid

Consider the following model

```
class MyModel # `Employee` used in concrete examples
  field :field1 # company_name used in concrete examples
  field :field2 # job_name used in concrete examples
  scope: filter1 # non_retired
  scope: filter2
end
```

- I need to filter / do named search queries, eg filter by non_retired
- I need to weights some fields (eg give 3 times more importance to some fields)
- I need to get statistics based on the **total** results (ie. not just the first 10 paginated results), for example, aggregating the company_names (I have already the code working, but I have problems on getting the "total" results ids.

I have problems putting all that together. From [Rails elasticsearch - named scope search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002833/rails-elasticsearch-named-scope-search) I understood that I needed to feed ids directly to Elasticsearch.

```
def search_by_id(query, type, ids, options = {})
  self.weighted_search(query, options.deep_merge({
    query: {
      multi_match: {
        filter: {
          ids: {
            values: ids
          }.tap do |filter|
          filter[:type] = type if type
        end
        }
      }
    }
  }))
end

def weighted_search(query, options = {})
  self.__elasticsearch__.search(
    {
      query: {
        multi_match: {
          query: query,
          fields: [
            "company_name^3",
            "job_name^2",
          ],
          # strategy: 'leap_frog_filter_first'
          # PROBLEM :cannot use this strategy on multi_match ?
        }
      }
    }.deep_merge(options)
  )
end
```

This is generating a BadRequest error with the following explanation

> [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_parsing_exception","reason":"[match] query does not support [$oid]

**I do not understand this error... I cannot filter by ids ??**

Then, suppose I have this working, how do I extract the subsets of ids that were a match for ElasticSearch ??

```
search = MyModel.search('query')
search.total_results # => 81
search.records.count # => 10
```

But I need to get all the 81 ids so I can perform some statistics (ie. aggregate the company names, I already have some code working, but now I only get the first 10 results aggregated...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my current solution (that I don't like because it hits the DBs a LOT)

- Use only MongoDB named scopes to filter record, and pluck their ids

  ```
  ids = @my_model_filtered.pluck(:id)
  ```
- Send the resulting IDs to ES, and do a scored search with boosts on specific fields

  ```
  def search_by_id(query, type, ids, options = {})
    self.weighted_search(query, options.deep_merge({
      query: {
        filtered: {
          filter: {
            ids: {
              values: ids.map(&:to_s)
            }.tap do |filter|
            filter[:type] = type if type
          end
          }
        }
      }
    }))
  end

  def weighted_search(query, options = {})
    self.__elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          filtered: {
            query: {
              multi_match: {
                query: query,
                fields: [
                  "company_name^3",
                  "job_name^2",
                  "xxx"
                ],
                type: "most_fields"
              }
            }
          }
        }
   }.deep_merge(options)
    )
   end
  ```
- Do additional information extraction (aggregations, etc.) on the MongoDB database with the list of IDs provided by Elasticsearch

  ```
  @response = @searching.search_by_id(@query, @searchable_type, ids).per(10000) # setting a high per number so ES returns all IDs
  @all_records = @response.records.records

  # Further processing
  @all_records.map_reduce(...)
  ```